# Kivy Buildozer AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: android, python-3.x, apk, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an apk for a simple python3/kivy app using buildozer in the virtual machine I got straight from kivy.org, this is day2. I had many errors, instaled pip, updated buildozer, pip installed morse, pnglab, sh, appdirs, setuptools for py3, now I'm at this error when I write $ buildozer android debug, my virtual machine uses python 2.7 and 3.4, anyone know what is this about? I would very much apreciate an answer as I am planning to make droid development my job some day, thank you. This is the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

And the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module> load_entry_point('buildozer==0.32dev', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.32dev-py3.4.eg /buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.32dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 992, in run_command
self.target.run_commands(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.32dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.32dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 97, in cmd_debug
self.buildozer.build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.32dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 198, in build
self.target.build_package()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/buildozer-0.32dev-py3.4.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 747, in build_package
apktitle = ''.join([x for x in config.get('app', 'title').decode('utf-8')
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in buildozer. You can possibly work around it by using python2. Feel free to create an issue about it on buildozer's github page.